# Admin Menu Hack (Left side in Dashboard)

Tags: menus, admin

How can I add a Title to my Admin Menu on the left side of the dashboard? Not a link, but just a title? I want do this in my functions and not use a plugin. Also which template file handles this menu?

**I found this but I have no idea of how to use it:**

**Adding a Word at the Beginning of the Menu**
This example will allow you to add the word of your choice to the beginning of your menu as a list item. In this example, the word "Menu:" is added at the beginning. You may want to set an id on the list item ("item-id" in this example) so that you can use CSS to style it.

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'items_wrap' => '<ul><li     
id="item-id">Menu: </li>%3$s</ul>' ) ); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Menu items are added to the left hand dashboard menu with a few different functions, depending on where you want it to display.  You will probably want to use [add_menu_page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_menu_page).  The last parameter of this function will determine how far up/down it displays.  These are the defaults that you can position your item around:

> **Positions for Core Menu Items**
>
> 2 Dashboard  4 Separator  5 Posts  10 Media  15 Links  20 Pages  25
>   Comments  59 Separator  60 Appearance  65 Plugins  70 Users  75 Tools 
>   80 Settings  99 Separator

In your active theme's functions.php file, you'll want to add the menu item and include a javascript file.

```
add_action('admin_menu','my_non_clickable_menu_item');
function my_non_clickable_menu_item() {
    add_menu_page( 'Title', 'Title', 'update_plugins', 'whatever/whatever', '', '', 50 );
}

add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts','enqueue_my_menu_js');
function enqueue_my_menu_js() {
    wp_enqueue_script('my_menu.js',/path/to/my_menu.js');
}
```

This will create a menu item called Title that goes to the non-existent whatever/whatever page.  We're going to use string to target it later, and you can change it to whatever you want.  To view this menu item, a user must have the 'update_plugins' ability, which by default is restricted to administrators.  The two blank parameters are a custom icon and a function that displays the content of the link, we don't need those.  The 50 is the position.  It will create it like so:
[image]

In your javascript file:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('a').click(function(e) {
        if($(this).attr('href') == 'whatever/whatever') {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });

    $('ul#adminmenu').find('a').each(function(e) {
        if($(this).attr('href') == 'whatever/whatever') {
            $(this).css('color','#000').css('cursor','default');
        }
    });
});
```

This will turn "Title" black (the #000), make the cursor not change to a pointer on hover and have it not do anything when it's clicked.  This will slow your admin section down just a bit, but it shouldn't be much of a problem.  You can style it further through the jquery css() function, like adding a border, or you could remove the icon to it's left.  Find out how to target it using a program like firebug or other developer tools in browsers.

Comment: Man that's complicated as He(Double L Hockey sticks), theres no core file that I can just go in and add a li to?

Comment: Nope, the menu is built dynamically.

Comment: Ohhhh got you! Dang that caught me by surprise... Well question: There is no way to get to #adminmenu ul?

Comment: You could append a list item to it with jquery http://api.jquery.com/append/

Comment: If I was to go the JQuery way where would I need to enter the coding. How would I go about using that technique. and again I do not mind editing core files so if there is an easier to all of this by editing a core file I do not care

Comment: You would put it in a separate javascript file and enqueue (include) that file as shown in the answer.

Comment: Hey man do you have Skype or are you on Facebook... Would like to Chat with you about what I'm experimenting with in Wordpress

Comment: My personal email is listed in my profile, you can get a hold of me that way.  Always happy to talk about development projects.

Comment: Hey man, I didnt see you email I have a question on Jquery Menus, and removing a top level admin menu on the left admin bar.

Comment: It's andrew dot bartel at gmail dot com